# Can you explain where this structure can be used?

Tags: grammar, usage, structure

Can you explain where this structure can be used?
Some of samples for the structure I'm reffering to are as it follows:

1. These are messages sent by telegraph
2. Talk about something connected to our topic
3. Bring me the phones made in China.

For instance, in this example: "messages sent by telegraph". The way I thought it must be written is like this: "messages that were sent by telegraph". The examples considered, I guess we can omit "that be". But to make sure I wanted to ask is the way I comprehend it is accurate and where and when it is used?

Comment: You might want to look up something called **whiz-deletion**.  Basically, if you can say something like "Talk about something **which is** connected to our topic" or "Bring me the phones **which were** made in China", you can leave out the "which is" part.

Comment: This sentence structure can be used anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> These are messages sent by telegraph.
>
> These are messages that were sent by telegraph.

> Talk about something connected to our topic.
>
> Talk about something that is connected to our topic.

> Bring me the phones made in China.
>
> Bring me the phones that were made in China.

There is no difference in meaning in these pairs of sentences but the shorter form is preferable.